# TypeScript produces unreachable code

Tags: javascript, typescript, transpiler

I have written the following function in TypeScript

```
function initializeTasksPerUserJSON(task)
{
    const tasksPerUser = {
        'username': task.mantisUsername,
        'duration_minutes': task.mantisBugNoteDurationSum,
        'categories': {
            [task.mantisBugCategoryName]: initializeTaskCategoriesJSON(task)
        }
    };

    return tasksPerUser;
}
```

which transpiles to the following JavaScript

```
function initializeTasksPerUserJSON(task) {
    var tasksPerUser = {
        'username': task.mantisUsername,
        'duration_minutes': task.mantisBugNoteDurationSum,
        'categories': (_a = {},
            _a[task.mantisBugCategoryName] = initializeTaskCategoriesJSON(task),
            _a
        )
    };
    return tasksPerUser;
    var _a;
}
```

I don't understand what the `var _a;` after the return statement is supposed to accomplish. It seems nonsensical to me since the line is never executed. Is this a bug in TypeScript, or is there a deeper meaning to it?

I am using tsc version 1.8.10 without any compiler flags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not a bug, this is only **[variable hoisting](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-hoisting-explained--net-15092)**.Every `var` declarations are going **to the top** of the function.You `Javascript` will be equivalent to this.

```
function initializeTasksPerUserJSON(task) {
    var _a; // See here
    var tasksPerUser;
    tasksPerUser = {
        'username': task.mantisUsername,
        'duration_minutes': task.mantisBugNoteDurationSum,
        'categories': (_a = {},
            _a[task.mantisBugCategoryName] = initializeTaskCategoriesJSON(task),
            _a
        )
    };
    return tasksPerUser;

}
```

You can also see [**this**](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html) .

Comment: I don't think "translated" is a good term. More like "equivalent to". People may end up thinking there is another transpiler along the way

Comment: Translated how, and by whom?

Comment: @BillyTom not translated but equivalent. By Engine

Comment: See? I managed to predict this question 2 seconds before it was posted :)

Comment: @Stilgar Agree with you.Changed

Comment: Is there a way to prevent this behaviour? Our testing framework reports that the `var _a;` is unreachable code, and it negatively affects our code coverage.

Comment: @BillyTom it is embedded in the Typescript compiler.As I know you can't change it.Or you need to change it manually